# My passport got stolen in Barcelona ,Spain

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, barcelona, lost-documents

I am on Sweden tourist visa and my passport got stolen in Barcelona and I am non EU national person i.e. Indian.

I got the police report but as I have return flight from Barcelona to Stockholm on Monday by RyanAir and I don't think in the mean time I will be able to get the passport from Indian embassy

Can I travel on police report to Stockholm? Please help

Comment: Have you called RyanAir to ask them what you should do?  Have you tried to reach the Swedish authorities?

Comment: I would put the Indian embassy on the call list immediately after the police, and ahead of StackExchange.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate as the traveler in that case seems to have been an EU national: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/my-id-was-stolen-during-my-stay-in-spain-will-ryanair-let-me-board-the-flight/64265

Answer (score 9):

Being a victim of crime, and especially having your passport stolen, is a circumstance in which you should contact your embassy's [after-hours emergency contact](http://www.embassyindia.es/consular-services/contacts-for-consular-services) phone number.

For Spain, that number is +34 6 1975 2305.

You will need to *either* [apply for a duplicate passport, or an emergency certificate to return directly to India](http://www.embassyindia.es/consular-services/passport-loss-by-tourist-businessman-general-visitor-to-spain).

You should expect either process to take close to a full day; it is possible you might not make it to your flight on Monday. You should mention when you call the embassy that you have a flight on Monday, to see if they can help you.