# Flying Ryanair from Germany, how do I check in for a flight if my passport was stolen?

Tags: passports, germany, check-in, ryanair, lost-documents

I went to Germany for a one week holiday and unfortunately my wallet with my passport inside was stolen in Berlin. I went to my embassy and they provided me with an emergency travel document so I can go back to the UK. Also I have a police report.

However my flight is on Tuesday from Hamburg and it is time to check in and there are not any options apart from passport or ID when you do check in, therefore I spoke to Ryanair Customer Service and they have told me that I am not able to check in or board a plane without valid ID/PASSPORT.

Does anyone know if I can check in and board a plane with an authorised emergency travel document?

Comment: I've been looking on the Ryanair website for you but not found anything yet. The question is, will Ryanair accept an emergency travel document as equivalent to a passport or as a valid form of national ID? I'd suggest getting the embassy to ask them on your behalf, what with Ryanair being famously unhelpful and all.

Comment: Yes, I am worried that they will not let me board a plane without a valid ID or Passport. I tried to contact their company using provided phone numbers on their website, but none of them is working. therefore there is no answer on my question and I start to panic because my flight is just 2 nights away.

Comment: [This question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/my-id-was-stolen-during-my-stay-in-spain-will-ryanair-let-me-board-the-flight?rq=1) was ultimately resolved by them being allowed to board, so I expect the real question here is "how does one check in". I'd suggest just trying turning up at the airport and trying to get them to waive the fee because you were unable to online, or putting in the details from your lost passport if you have them.

Comment: @AE I'm pretty sure they will accept an emergency travel document issued by an embassy. Anecdotally from speaking to my airline industry friends I've never come across an airline that would not.

Comment: "The question is, will Ryanair accept an emergency travel document as equivalent to a passport or as a valid form of national ID?" -> what would emergency documents be good for if they weren't accepted anywhere? I'd assume that if a regular passport is enough for the given destination (think no additional visas required etc) then an emergency replacement should be as well.

Comment: Ryanair can be very unhelpful I suggest you keep on trying or use their on line chat service good luck !

Comment: We once checked in with a library card (with a picture) on a back flight since the ID was forgotten at home, being nice and talking with the people will always help a lot.

Comment: In 2006 a friend in a similar situation was able to board a return Ryanair flight with their emergency travel document.

Answer (score 28):

I can't find anything about emergency travel documents in their Ts&Cs, but I've found this relevant exchange from Ryanair's official twitter account:

> Ann ‏@ann_nguyen1  16 Jul 2015 
>   @Ryanair I only have my emergency travel document and I'm flying on Sat from Manch home to Norway. Can I still board the flight?Pls say YES
>
> Ryanair ‏@Ryanair  16 Jul 2015
>   @ann_nguyen1 Hi, Can you advise who issued the document? TB
>
> Ann ‏@ann_nguyen1  16 Jul 2015
>   @Ryanair I just need to get home on Saturday! I have all the valid IDs with me. Emergency Travel Documents and my Norwegian ID.
>
> RyanairVerified account @Ryanair 
>   @ann_nguyen1 **Emergency Travel Document issued by the Embassy is a valid travel document.** GK
>   3:10 AM - 16 Jul 2015
>
> Ann ‏@ann_nguyen1  16 Jul 2015
>   @Ryanair thanks so much for the prompt reply!!! <3
>
> Ann ‏@ann_nguyen1  16 Jul 2015
>   @Ryanair one last Q. How do I check-in online when I don't have my passport?
>
> Ryanair ‏@Ryanair  16 Jul 2015
>   @ann_nguyen1 If there's a number on the travel document, put it as passport or check in at the airport (free of charge in this case). GK
>
> Ann ‏@ann_nguyen1  16 Jul 2015
>   @Ryanair also, would you be able to email me a confirmation of this? That I am OK to travel with an ETD.
>
> Ryanair ‏@Ryanair  16 Jul 2015
>   @ann_nguyen1 Emergency Travel Document is clasified as passport replacement and therefore no need for additional written confirmations. GK

https://twitter.com/ryanair/status/621622832888442880?lang=en

I'd suggest you contact Ryanair Customer Services again and explain that you have an Emergency Travel Document which is classified by Ryanair as a passport replacement and you'd like them to put a note on your account confirming for the airport staff that this is a valid document for travel.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer from laws, but from experience:

My Spanish ID expired while in Germany and travelling with Ryanair.

The embassy made a safe-conduct for my trip and Ryanair did have no problem letting me in the flight with that.

I read somewhere that under EU law you need a valid ID, not a non-expired ID to flight, however most of low-cost companies love to have an excuse to not let you in, because they get your money (its your fault). However, anecdotally also, I have used my expired ID to get into flights within the Star alliance without any problem but a "you are a mess, travelling with an expired ID" look.

Rules about expired IDs [flying to and from Germany](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/expired-lost-passports/germany/index_en.htm). Also, there is a [button here](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm#!lightbox-uid-0) to choose any other EU county.

Note again, this is the country's law. Any airline reserves the right to not let you in.

Comment: Valid=non-expired, unless the destination country has provisions for expired documents (most commonly for their own citizens)

Comment: @Crazydre I will try to find the source of this, but I did read it in some legal stuff. : Valid=issued legally by a government, but not necessarily non-expired.

Comment: @Crazydre It is nationality dependent, but for Spanish: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/expired-lost-passports/spain/index_en.htm

Comment: Yep, the European Agreement on Regulations governing the Movement of Persons between Member States of the Council of Europe. It lets nationals of most member states to travel between the states (which even includes Turkey) on a passport expired by no more than 5 years. Such a passport is not technically valid though; rather it's expired but nonetheless accepted